# Iterate over pairs in order of sum of absolute values

Tags: python

I want to iterate over pairs of integers in order of the sum of their absolute values.  The list should look like:

```
(0,0)
(-1,0)
(0,1)
(0,-1)
(1,0)
(-2,0)
(-1,1)
(-1,-1)
(0,2)
(0,-2)
(1,1)
(1,-1)
(2,0)
[...]
```

For pairs with the same sum of absolute values I don't mind which order they come in.

Ideally I would like to be able to create the pairs forever so that I can use each one in turn. How can you do that?

For a fixed range I can make the list of pairs in an ugly way with:

```
sorted([(x,y)for x in range(-20,21)for y in range(-20,21)if abs(x)+abs(y)<21],key=lambda x:sum(map(abs,x))
```

This doesn't allow me to iterate forever and it also doesn't give me one pair at a time.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: There are infinitely many int pairs with an absolute sum of 0...

Comment: @Marat yes. But I want the pairs outputted in order of the sum of their absolute values. So (-10,10) will come quite late on.

Comment: My bad, I missed the "absolute" part

Comment: Do you care about the exact order as long as the sum of absolutes is maintained?

Comment: The first number is range(n) and the second is n minus that

Comment: @MadPhysicist no I don't.  If two pairs have the same sum of absolutes they can appear in any order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
from itertools import count  # Creates infinite iterator

def abs_value_pairs():
    for absval in count():  # Generate all possible sums of absolute values
        for a in range(-absval, absval + 1):  # Generate all possible first values
            b = abs(a) - absval  # Compute matching second value (arbitrarily do negative first)
            yield a, b
            if b:  # If first b is zero, don't output again, otherwise, output positive b
                yield a, -b
```

This runs forever, and operates efficiently (avoiding recomputing anything unnecessarily).

Comment: The innermost loop can be trivially unrolled with two yields

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Heh, I was in the process of figuring out the cleanest way to do it (now posted). Kept trying to redo or overdo things (computing the two `b`s independently when they're always each other's negation, testing `if b1 != b2:` when the test only fails when `b1` is `0`, etc.). It's been a long day. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This will do it.  If you really want it to be infinite, remove the firs `if` statement.

```
import itertools

def makepairs(count=3):
    yield (0,0)
    for base in itertools.count(1):
        if base > count:  # optional escape
            return        # optional escape
        for i in range(base+1):
            yield (i, base-i)
            if base != i:
                yield (i, i-base)
            if i:
                yield (-i, base-i)
                if base != i:
                    yield (-i, i-base)

print(list(makepairs(9)))
```

Comment: `itertools.count()` will be neater than `while True`

Comment: Neater in what way?  If they want it to be infinite, then `itertools.count()` serves no purpose. ------  I see.  Replace `base=0` and `base += 1` with `itertools.count`.  I withdraw my objection.

Comment: I made my own answer but it's practically the same as this one, so doesn't deserve a separate post. I'll just leave it here in case anyone cares: https://pastebin.com/5cvGX7WZ

Answer (score 2):

The solution below produces a sum stream with tuples of any length:

```
from itertools import count
def pairs(l = 2):
  def groups(d, s, c = []):
     if not d and sum(map(abs, c)) == s:
        yield tuple(c)
     elif d:
        for i in [j for k in d[0] for j in {k, -1*k}]:
           yield from groups(d[1:], s, c +[i])
  for i in count():
     yield from groups([range(i+1) for _ in range(l)], i)

p = pairs()
for _ in range(10):
   print(next(p))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make an infinite generator function:

```
def pairSums(s = 0): # base generation on target sum to get pairs in order
    while True:      # s parameter allows starting from a given sum
        for i in range(s//2+1):                            # partitions
            yield from {(i,s-i),(s-i,i),(i-s,-i),(-i,i-s)} # no duplicates
        s += 1                                             # next target sum
```

Output:

```
for p in pairSums(): print(p)
        
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, -1)
(1, 0)
(-1, 0)
(2, 0)
(-2, 0)
(0, -2)
(0, 2)
(1, 1)
(-1, -1)
(3, 0)
(0, 3)
(0, -3)
(-3, 0)
(1, 2)
(-1, -2)
(2, 1)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

First notice that you can lay your totals out in a grid for non-negative values:

```
x
3|3
2|23
1|123
0|0123
-+----
 |0123y
```

Here we can see a pattern where the diagonals are your totals. Let's just trace some systematic line through them. The following shows an order you could walk through them:

```
x
3|6
2|37
1|148
0|0259
-+----
 |0123y
```

Here the matrix contains the order of the iterations.

This solves your problem for non-negative values of x and y. To get the rest you can just negate x and y, making sure you don't do it for when they are zero. Something like this:

```
def generate_triplets(n):
    yield 0, (0, 0)
    for t in range(1, n + 1):  # Iterate over totals t
        for x in range(0, t + 1):  # Iterate over component x
            y = t - x  # Calclulate component y
            yield t, (x, y)  # Default case is non-negative
            if y > 0:
                yield t, (x, -y)
            if x > 0:
                yield t, (-x, y)
            if x > 0 and y > 0:
                yield t, (-x, -y)

def generate_pairs(n):
    yield from (pair for t, pair in generate_triplets(n))

# for pair in generate_pairs(10):
#     print(pair)

for t, (x, y) in generate_triplets(3):
    print(f'{t} = abs({x}) + abs({y})')
```

This outputs

```
0 = abs(0) + abs(0)
1 = abs(0) + abs(1)
1 = abs(0) + abs(-1)
1 = abs(1) + abs(0)
1 = abs(-1) + abs(0)
2 = abs(0) + abs(2)
2 = abs(0) + abs(-2)
2 = abs(1) + abs(1)
2 = abs(1) + abs(-1)
2 = abs(-1) + abs(1)
2 = abs(-1) + abs(-1)
2 = abs(2) + abs(0)
2 = abs(-2) + abs(0)
3 = abs(0) + abs(3)
3 = abs(0) + abs(-3)
3 = abs(1) + abs(2)
3 = abs(1) + abs(-2)
3 = abs(-1) + abs(2)
3 = abs(-1) + abs(-2)
3 = abs(2) + abs(1)
3 = abs(2) + abs(-1)
3 = abs(-2) + abs(1)
3 = abs(-2) + abs(-1)
3 = abs(3) + abs(0)
3 = abs(-3) + abs(0)
```

Or as pairs:

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, -1)
(1, 0)
(-1, 0)
(0, 2)
(0, -2)
(1, 1)
(1, -1)
(-1, 1)
(-1, -1)
(2, 0)
(-2, 0)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For each sum, walk the diagonal in one quadrant and rotate each coordinate into the other quadrants:

```
from itertools import count

def coordinates():
    yield 0, 0
    for sum in count(1):
        for x in range(sum):
            y = sum - x
            yield x, y
            yield y, -x
            yield -x, -y
            yield -y, x
```

Answer (score -1):

(I hope I understood the requirements) I used [itertools product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
>>> for i in sorted(itertools.product(range(-5, 4), range(-5, 4)), key=lambda tup: abs(tup[0]) + abs(tup[1])):
    print(i)
... 
(0, 0)
(-1, 0)
(0, -1)
(0, 1)
(1, 0)
(-2, 0)
(-1, -1)
(-1, 1)
(0, -2)
(0, 2)
(1, -1)
(1, 1)
(2, 0)
(-3, 0)
(-2, -1)
(-2, 1)
(-1, -2)
(-1, 2)
(0, -3)
(0, 3)
(1, -2)
(1, 2)
(2, -1)
...
```

Comment: This has three problems.  First, it will not generate infinitely.  Second, you are wasting effort by generating pairs that won't be used.  Third your ranges should probably be (-4,5), not (-5,4).  You want (-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4); your code doesn't do that.

Comment: The problem is that this won't give me pairs forever because of the `sorted`.  Edit: I agree with Tim Roberts.