# Make generator for pairs excluding those with a 0

Tags: python

I would like to generate pairs of integers forever sorted by the sum of their absolute values from smallest to biggest. However I don't want to return any that have a 0 for either part of the pair. So I would like:

```
(1, 1)
(-1, -1)
(1, 2)
(-1, -2)
(2, 1)
(-2, -1)
[...]
```

I saw [Iterate over pairs in order of sum of absolute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69637772/iterate-over-pairs-in-order-of-sum-of-absolute-values) which has really great answers such as:

```
def pairSums(s = 0): # base generation on target sum to get pairs in order
    while True:      # s parameter allows starting from a given sum
        for i in range(s//2+1):                            # partitions
            yield from {(i,s-i),(s-i,i),(i-s,-i),(-i,i-s)} # no duplicates
        s += 1
```

I could filter out the pairs with a 0 in them but that seems ugly and inefficient (most of the pairs seem to have a 0 in them). Is there way to generate them directly?

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to exclude the cases i=0 and i=s?

```
def pairSums(s = 0): # base generation on target sum to get pairs in order
    while True:      # s parameter allows starting from a given sum
        for i in range(1, s//2+1):                            # partitions
            if i != s:
                yield from {(i,s-i),(s-i,i),(i-s,-i),(-i,i-s)} 
        s += 1
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't follow the same order as OP's example. Not sure how important that is to OP.

Comment: @ddejohn The order for pairs with the same sum of absolute value is not important.